# Airflow render_template_as_native_obj still returns a string for dynamic tasks, expecting a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-xcom

I am using airflow version 2.4.3 composer version 2.1.11

```
# this function creates a dictionary of sql file names and file paths from google cloud
def _file_dict(*op_args):
    bucket=op_args[0]
    path=op_args[1]
    from google.cloud import storage
    client = storage.Client()
    blobs = client.list_blobs(bucket, prefix=path)
    my_dict={}
    for blob in blobs:
        if(blob.name.endswith('.sql')):
            my_dict[blob.name]=blob.path
    print(my_dict.items())
    return my_dict

# and this function creates a bigquery task for each sql file
def _sql_file(file_nm:str, file_path:str, dag=None):
    hook = GCSHook()
    print(f'bucket name: {dag_bucket}')
    print(f'sql file name: {file_nm}')
    print(f'sql file path: {file_path}')    
    try:
        object_name = f'{file_path}/{file_nm}'
        resp_byte = hook.download_as_byte_array(
            bucket_name = dag_bucket,
            object_name = object_name,
        )
    except:
        e = sys.exc_info()
        print(e)
        sys.exit(1)
    resp_string = resp_byte.decode("utf-8")
    return BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
        task_id=f'create_view_{file_nm}',
        configuration={
            "query": {
                "query": f'{resp_string}',
                "useLegacySql": False,
            }
        },
        location='US',
        dag=dag
    )

dag = DAG(dag_name,
    default_args=default_args,
    catchup=True,
    max_active_runs=1,
    schedule_interval=schedule_interval,
    description=dag_description,
    render_template_as_native_obj=True,
)

make_file_dict = PythonOperator(
    task_id='make_file_dict',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=_file_dict,
    op_args=[ (dag_bucket),('view_definitions') ],
    dag=dag
)

file_dict = "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='make_file_dict') }}"

run_sql_from_file = [
    _sql_file(file_nm=k, file_path=v, dag=dag)
    for k,v in file_dict.items()
]

make_file_dict>>run_sql_from_file
```

I was expecting the xcom_pull to result in a dictionary because render_template_as_native_obj is true.  There are aspects of airflow/python that I don't understand yet (namely decorators and jinja templates) and I'm clearly doing something wrong, but I'm not sure how to make this work.

If I create a dictionary of hardcoded the values, it works fine.  I'd rather not do that for 2 reasons: 1) I want the job to automatically pick up any .sql files that are pushed into the repo and 2) there are a lot of files.

Any help is appreciated.

the error is

```
Broken DAG: [/home/airflow/gcs/dags/basic_view_dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/basic_view_dag.py", line 165, in <module>
    for k,v in file_dict.items()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I have tried and failed with the following variations

```
ast.literal_eval("{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='make_file_dict') }}")

json.loads("{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='make_file_dict') }}")

def str_to_dict(string):
    string = string.strip('{}')
    string = string.strip('[]')
    pairs = string.split(', ')
    return {key[1:-2]: int(value) for key, value in (pair.split(': ') for pair in pairs)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the `file_dict` properly. Try passing that as `op_args` or `op_kwargs` to your ptyhon_callable. That'll make airflow render the jinja template and pass it as a literal to the function.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to do that?

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76315284/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).